Unity multiple LocalizedString into one LocalizeStringEvent
I try to dynamically change a localized text with this methods :
private void SetWorldMessage(string key)
    {
        LocalizedString localizedString = new(TABLE_REFERENCE, key)
        {
            { WORLD_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT, currentWave }
        };
        worldMessageEvent.StringReference = localizedString;
        worldMessageEvent.StringReference.RefreshString();
    }

The two texts take the same parameter.
It works only on the first call. It shows that my table references, key and argument are correctly initialized but the text won't change and the value is not updated.
worldMessageEvent is a LocalizeStringEvent :

Any idea what's wrong ?
I tried to initialized two LocalizedString and use it instead of building it. But no luck, even the first time.
Edit : In debug mode, I see that the string is actualized correctly in worldMessageEvent in my script and Editor. It's only my TextMeshPro that it's not updated.
Edit 2 : worldMessageEvent.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = localizedString.GetLocalizedString();
Seem to do the work but I think it's not very elegant.

That is usually due to the fact strings are passed by value in c#. I don't know what StringReference is but if it is a string, when you set it equal to localizedString only the value is passed. Thus in debugging localizedString is correct but the TextmeshProUGUI is stuck on the old value because it has not been refreshed which is what that last bit of 'Not elegant' code is doing.
